# find limit without using Cauchy's Definitions

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of this:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^\frac{2}{3}$$[\sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x}]$

since I'm not allowed to use any of Cauchy's definitions of the limit, i tried to divide by x.

=$\sqrt[3]{x^2}$  $[\sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x}]$
=$[\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2} - \sqrt[3]{x^3}]$ = =$[\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2} - x]$

and so I divided by x and got $[\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1x}$ - 1]

and since $\frac1x$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity and so it'd be  $[\sqrt[3]{1+0} - 1]=0.$

but I already know the answer is supposed to be $\frac13$, and I'm not sure why this method doesn't work and what else could i try.

Comment: If you divide by $x$, you must multiply by $x$ too

Comment: Hint: $a-b = (a^3-b^3)/(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Consider $a=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Plugging $a=\sqrt[3]{x+1}, b=\sqrt[3]{x}$, we get $$1=x+1-x=(\sqrt[3]{x+1})^3-(\sqrt[3]{x+1})^3=(\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{x})\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right),$$ so $$\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{x}=\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)}$$ and $$x^{2/3}(\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{x})=\dfrac{x^{2/3}}{\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)}$$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $x^{2/3}$, we get that $$\dfrac{x^{2/3}}{\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(x+1)x}{x^2}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x^2}{x^2}}\right)}=$$ $$=\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}+1\right)},$$
and the result, $\dfrac{1}{3}$, follows immediately.